# Daily video log app ubuntu like Jake Sully's from avatar

Tags: video, log

Is there anything daily video log for Ubuntu 20.4 LTS GNU like Jake Sully's from avatar did? The image has been attached for a better understanding:

[image: Daily video log app ubuntu like Jake Sully's from avatar]

Comment: Are you looking for a full-featured application that organizes and records? Or just something that records? 

Comment: something like that record will be ok but if available full-featured application, will be great

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of applications that can record video from a webcam. I can't say which is the best for what you would like to do, as I don't know how closely you would like your video logs to resemble what we see in the movies.

Here are some that seem to be more popular than others (in no particular order):

- [Cheese](https://help.gnome.org/users/cheese/stable/) ⇠ you may already have this on your machine
- [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/download) ⇠ very popular tool, though a little overwhelming for some people at the beginning
- [Kamoso](https://apps.kde.org/kamoso/)
- [Webcamoid](https://webcamoid.github.io/)

There are also a bunch of video recorders that are primarily suited for video surveillance, but can be used to record from a webcam (or external camera) in a number of video formats, with or without the motion-detection start/stop element enabled.

Comment: Cheese is good but not properly adjust with sound during the video. I have tried that before posting this. Is there any way to modify Cheese. Actually, I think Cheese can do something like that I mentioned.